# How to change Kivy AccorditionItem button's color?

Tags: button, colors, accordion, kivy, kivy-language

I don't know if the `title bar` of an `AccorditionItem` is a real button (It seems to be visually identical), but what i need is to do the same thing that can be done in a normal button, as follow:

```
<Button>
    background_color: .55,.5,.95,.6
```

I've tried to apply this propriety to an `accorditionitem` but obviously it has not worked.

Thus, how can I apply the properties of `background_color` found in a button element in the "button"(title bar) element of an `AccordionItem`?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing color - impossible without editing the code(which is pretty easy btw) and even then it'd be tinting.

Changing *image* however is something you may use out-of-box:

```
AccordionItem(background_normal='somethin.xyz')
```

where you can change the default "color", but of course you'll need to create those images yourself. Look at [these](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.accordion.html#kivy.uix.accordion.AccordionItem.background_disabled_normal) properties and use them to customize the `AccordionItem`.

Also, there's no `Button` if I'm right, those are only `Layout`s, therefore no `*color` properties, only behavior. But yeah, you can take it as a `Button` if it does the job. :)

**Edit:**
About the size of background image, I think even 1x1 is enough if you allow it to stretch. For more fancy effects i.e. borders, "3D", etc. draw more than a single color to that image and you'll see.

Also, you can build your own template with kv for [`title_template`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.accordion.html#kivy.uix.accordion.AccordionItem.title_template).

**Edit2:**
[Pull Request](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4296) used to make `color` and `disabled_color` available for `AccordionItem`.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your help. I checked the AccorditionItems properties before and i saw that they are similar to  those of the button except for background_color. Please can show me how to change color by code?

Comment: Oh thanks man, you are awesome! :D Side observation: I think this widget needs a little modernization considering that it uses the "old" template method for styling the element (instead of the Rules). It will be more easy for customization. Unfortunately I am not able to apply this kind of improvement to the code. :(

Comment: You can make a feature request with an example, though I think it can be customized even now because of the `title_template`(the Label) and the body functions would still remain the same. The only thing that could be changed is maybe the title's thickness.